# Slick slider property swipeToSlide is not working on RTL using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, slick.js

I am using Angular 12, and Slick 0.5.1. The problem i am facing is swipeToSlide is working fine in LTR, but in RTL it is not working at all. I am updating rtl value dynamically.

```
slideConfig = {
    "slidesToShow": 10,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    touchThreshold: 309,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    dots: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    rtl: this.isRTL
};
```

Anyone please help me to fix the issue.

I just found that if i remove variableWidth: true, it start working fine, but i need that property